# Solution of a nonlinear system of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to solve this system of equations of second degree in set of real numbers

$$15(x+y)=(15+x+y)x$$
$$(15+x+y)x=12\sqrt{x^2-6^2}+9\sqrt{y^2-(9/2)^2}+108 $$

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how do you obtain this system ? (maybe there is some simpler way to solve your initial problem?)

Comment: "The question is widely applicable to a large audience" says the bounty message. Is it really? If there's a general method being sought here, I don't see it explicitly asked for.

Comment: May be the following remark will be useful: the right part of the 2nd equation can be rewritten as $$(\sqrt{x^2-6^2}+6)^2 + (\sqrt{y^2-(9/2)^2}+9/2)^2+ 108-x^2-y^2$$

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that comes to mind is to use the first equation to express one variable using the other:
$$15(x+y)=(15+x+y)x\iff 15y=x^2+xy\iff y(15-x)=x^2\iff y=\frac{x^2}{15-x}$$
(since $x=15$ is not a solution). Now substitute this into the second equation:
$$15\left(x+\frac{x^2}{15-x}\right)=\frac{225x}{15-x}=12\sqrt{x^2-6^2}+9\sqrt{\frac{x^4}{(15-x)^2}-(9/2)^2}+108$$
$$\begin{align*}\frac{75x}{15-x}-36&=4\sqrt{x^2-6^2}+3\sqrt{\frac{x^4}{(15-x)^2}-(9/2)^2}\\
3\frac{37x-180}{15-x}&=4\sqrt{x^2-6^2}+3\frac{\sqrt{4x^4-81(15-x)^2}}{2(15-x)}
\end{align*}$$
Squaring: 
$$9\frac{(37x-180)^2}{(15-x)^2}=16(x^2-6^2)+3\frac{4x^4-81(15-x)^2}{4(15-x)^2}+24\frac{\sqrt{x^2-6^2}\sqrt{4x^4-81(15-x)^2}}{2(15-x)}$$
Rearanging:
$$\frac{-76 x^4+1920 x^3+37431 x^2-555930 x+1739475}{12(15-x)}=\sqrt{x^2-6^2}\sqrt{4x^4-81(15-x)^2}$$
Squaring and rearanging (using [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2836%2837x-180%29%5E2-64%28x%5E2-6%5E2%29%2815-x%29%5E2-3%284x%5E4-81%2815-x%29%5E2%29%29%5E2-12%5E2%2815-x%29%5E2%28x%5E2-6%5E2%29%284x%5E4-81%2815-x%29%5E2%29)) once again, we have:
$$5200 x^8-274560 x^7-2100312 x^6+226914480 x^5-978099543 x^4-35070717420 x^3+439302361950 x^2-1928383969500 x+3004515635625=0$$
Which has 4 real and 4 non-real roots. Following the above calculation, one can check that the conditions before each squaring imply that none of those solutions solves the initial equation. Hence there is no solution.

Comment: It is a little cleaner to replace the left side of the second with $15(x+y)$, but will still be a mess.

Comment: After substitution and simplification, and if I made no mistake, I get an 8th degree polynomial in x with 4 real roots, none of which gives a solution of the initial system. Thus no solution.

Comment: Can you prove that

Comment: With Maxima, yes. By hand it's a bit harder :-)

Comment: Can you show the link to Maxima

Comment: @Milingona Ana: I edited my answer.

Comment: In your line after "Squaring:", haven't you forgotten to square the 3?

Comment: Yes, I have :'(